# JOIN performance: affected by primary key choice or column order?

Tags: mysql, indexing, sql-update, query-optimization, primary-key

I have a table `labor` with 20 columns and 30 millions rows. One column `lab_id` is a foreign key and has an index (not unique). Another table `map` has 10 columns and has primary key `id` and an unique indexed column `lab_id`. I would like to update some columns in `labor` with the content in `map`:

```
UPDATE labor r
INNER JOIN map m ON r.lab_id = m.lab_id
SET r.col5 = m.col5
  , r.col6 = m.col6
  , r.col7 = m.col7
;
```

`labor.lab_id`could be placed as second column or as last column. Does the place of the indexed column which is used to join affect the performance of updating?

Does performance change if `map.id`is deleted and `map.lab_id`is defined as primary key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of columns in the table makes no measurable difference.

The choice of primary key *does* make a difference in InnoDB. That storage engine uses a table's primary key as a so-called *[clustered index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-index-types.html)*. The contents of the table are stored in that clustered index, rather than in some other part of the DBMS's table space. Therefore, when your query references the primary key, the query planner has immediate access to the rest of the data in the row.

By contrast, non-primary keys, even unique ones (in InnoDB) retrieve the primary key, and the query planner uses that primary key to access the clustered index. So row references via the primary key need one less data access operation. That adds up.

If your `id` column is an autoincrement column and you wish to keep using it that way, you can put it into a unique index, then change the primary key.  A DDL statement similar to this will do the trick.

```sql
ALTER TABLE map
     ADD UNIQUE INDEX id(id),
     DROP PRIMARY KEY,
     ADD PRIMARY KEY (lab_id);
```

This might be a good way to go, because your table will continue to function with no changes to your existing software.

This kind of DDL statement wrangles multiple keys all at once. It is the most efficient way to make your changes because it does all the table reorganizing at once. It still takes time.

As for performance. Insert/update performance doesn't change much: inserts and updates still require checking and updating two unique keys. Querying performance will change for the better.

(None of the above applies to the MyISAM or AriaDB storage engines.)

Comment: Perfect answer with very useful  information. I got new insights.